# Excel VBA If Statement

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test()

Dim score As Integer, result As String
score = Range("A1").Value
If score > 0 Then result = "pass"

 Range("b1").Value = result

End Sub
```

I'm missing something here. In cell A1 i have 0.04 which is > 0
But in B1 I'm not returning pass

Comment: Step through the code (F8 in VBA editor). Where does it go wrong?

Comment: In math, whole numbers are also called integers. In VBA, the `Integer` data type is used to store whole numbers between ‑32768 and 32768. The preferred data type is `Long` though since it covers more whole numbers. If you need to store decimal numbers, then you need to use the `Double` type: `Dim score As Double`. BTW, 0.04 is automatically converted to a zero if you use the `Integer` data type hence the 'surprising' behavior. Check out the [Docs' data type summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary).

Comment: @VBasic2008: You should write the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to VBA, it may be better to reference cells and their `.Value` property, which is a `Variant`, and is designed to handle values of multiple types more intuitively:

```
Sub test()
    Dim score As Range: Set score = Range("A1")
    Dim result As Range: Set result = Range("B1")
    If 0 < score.Value Then
        result.Value = "pass"
'    Else
'        result.Value = "fail"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Populate Conditionally

- You have chosen the wrong data type for `Score` as I mentioned in your comments.
- You want to use the *Long* data type for whole numbers (see [this legendary post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520) why not *Integer*) and the ***Double*** data type for decimal numbers.
- For more information on data types, read through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary).

```vb
Sub PopulateConditionally()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Could be anything (number, string, boolean, error) so use a 'Variant' type.
    Dim CellValue As Variant: CellValue = ws.Range("A1").Value
    
    Dim Score As Double, Result As String
    
    If VarType(CellValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
        Score = CDbl(CellValue) ' explicit conversion (you're in control)
        'Or:
        'Score = CellValue ' implicit conversion (VBA is in control)
        If Score > 0 Then
            Result = "pass"
        'Else ' <=0; do nothing; 'Result' remains an empty string ("")
        End If
    'Else ' is not a number; do nothing; 'Result' remains an empty string ("")
    End If
    
    ws.Range("B1").Value = Result

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For this line "Dim score As Integer" you will have to change data type to variant or double. As its integer 0.04 will be stored as 0 in the variable